# /usr/java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/java.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, java

I've been trying to run a plugin inside a I have hired, and I've constantly been getting this error:

```
[04:13:41] /bin/sh: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/java.exe: No such file or directory
```

Not too sure what's causing it or how to fix it, the owner cannot be contacted so that's not an option for me.

I've tried downgrading my java, but this still occurs.

Comment: It's unlikely that java will have a .exe extension on Linux,

Comment: "inside a I have hired": Inside a *what*?

Comment: OP, seriously??

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run .exe file on linux os!?
That's might be the issue..
Try to get a version the fits your os.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this script is attempting to run the Java runtime using
the name `java.exe` at a specific path. `.exe` usually indicates
Windows executables; on Unix, executables usually do not have an
extension.

I would suggest editing your script looking for the line where it raises the
error you quoted, and changing the call to be the full path to `java` as
installed on your system (which you might find using `which java`), or
perhaps just `java`.